# Is there a command to remove previously installed .pkg package?

Tags: command-line, bash, macos, pkg

I have installed a `.pkg` package with the `installer` command. But there are problem with that installation. Now I want to remove it. Is there a standard way to do it with command line interface?

Note: I have no access to the GUI interface of the machine.

Comment: Do you want to share the pkg? They can be nested and have pre and post scripts. Those are not reversible in general.If you just want the hypothetical, I could flush this out into an answer that says no and here is why...

Comment: @bmike Well, you could list its contents with `lsbom` and delete those, but this won't reverse things done by the installation scripts.

Comment: 100% correct @maxreid - also, any packages that [violate the “commandments”](https://www.afp548.com/2010/06/03/the-commandments-of-packaging-in-os-x/) will fail in incomplete and/or bad and spectacular ways - see the recent google keystone deleting /var and zoom.us installing malware and security exploits as part of the preflight script, etc...

Comment: @bmike: I installed a newer version of [git](https://git-scm.com/) on an old mac. The binary doesn't work so I want to remove it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/525395/161451

Comment: If you still have the original `.pkg`, the [Suspicious Package](https://mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) app can be a nice way to see what files are installed by the package and where, see what scripts are run by the package, and inspecting any installer receipts from previous installations.

It's a nice complement to the answers given here, especially for inspecting any installer scripts that may be present (as discussed, you would be on your own for figuring out how to reverse any changes those scripts may have made).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use pkgUtil for it.

```
$ pkgutil --pkgs # list all installed packages
$ pkgutil --files the-package-name.pkg # list installed files
```

After visually inspecting the list of files you can do something like the following:

**I leave this up to you as modifying files with root user maybe a bit risky**

```
$ pkgutil --pkg-info the-package-name.pkg # check the location
$ cd / # assuming the package is rooted at /...
$ pkgutil --only-files --files the-package-name.pkg | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -o -n 1 -0 sudo rm -i
```

To remove directories as well as files, list the directories from the package using:

```
$ pkgutil --only-dirs --files the-package-name.pkg
```

The following command could be used to attempt removal of each directory, although be aware that when System Integrity Protection is active, there are some file paths that not even the root user may modify. **Nevertheless — and needless to say — extreme care should always be taken when removing files with root privileges.**

```
$ pkgutil --only-dirs --files the-package-name.pkg | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -o -n 1 -0 sudo rm -ir
```

Once you’ve uninstalled the files, you can remove the receipt with:

```
$ sudo pkgutil --forget the-package-name.pkg
```

For more details, see the <kbd>pkgutil</kbd> main page.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/525395/161451

Comment: The command with `sudo rm -ir` is extremely dangerous! The directories listed by `pkgutil --only-dirs --files` include all parent directories, so if the package installed **anything** in `/usr/`, the command given would attempt to remove all of `/usr/`! Using `rmdir` would be much more appropriate to ensure that only **empty** directories are removed, but the best option would be to manually inspect and remove any leftover directories to ensure you are only removing directories that were created exclusively by/for the package.